# return a matrix of integers

Tags: c++, matrix

Hi I'm creating a Matrix object which is a containter for an `int[3][3]`.

I want to add a get_matrix() function which returns the object itself or the pointer to it, but I'm not able. 
eclipse says :

> Type cannot convert ‘int (*)[3][3]’ to ‘int**’

```
enter code here
class Matrix
{
  private:
  int matrix[3][3];

  public:

  void set_matrix()
  {
      int c, d;
      printf("Enter the elements of first matrix1\n");

      for (c = 0; c < n_rows; c++)
        for (d = 0; d < n_column; d++)
          scanf("%d", &matrix[c][d]);
  }

  int get_matrix(){
      return matrix;
  }

  void output_matrix()
  {
      int c, d;
        for (c = 0; c < n_rows; c++) {
            printf("\n");
          for (d = 0; d < n_column; d++)
            printf("%d\t", matrix[c][d]);
        }
  }
};
```

Comment: use C++ container for matrix instead C-array or pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
int **get_matrix() const {
    return reinterpret_cast<int **>(matrix);
}
```

or this:

```
int **get_matrix() const {
    return (int **) matrix;
}
```

A two dimensioned array *cannot* be implicitly converted to a pointer to a pointer to an `int`, although there are several similarities between the two. You can, however, force a cast to an `int **`.

You could also (and probably should) use a C++ container that is readily available instead of trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: You should try to compile that.

Comment: That would show you that an array of arrays *cannot* be implicitly converter to a pointer to pointer. See [here](http://ideone.com/tkr71v).

Comment: @juanchopanza - I understand. That code was off the top of my head. I have updated with two examples I just compiled without warnings or errors.